# Disabling the java.awt.robot inside of a browser

Tags: java, awtrobot

Would it be possible to disable a Java program that contains a Robot from running inside of a browser? I don't think so, but I figured I'd ask anyway.

For example, a robot that clicks the the "Ask Question" button on the SO site can be created in Java (based on the pixel location of the "Ask Question" button) using the Robot class. Can somebody alter the stack-overflow website such that said Java program can't run on it?

Comment: Only if you also have the website disable the mouse and keyboard too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they could alter the site and move the button or add a captcha challenge or something like that, but essentially, to the SO servers a request from your java program looks like any other request.

Answer (score 1):

Web site admins really only have the request URL and the request headers for filtering or blocking traffic. You can't manage requests from java.awt.robot directly; you'll have to look for something else to work with.